# How does the Android Market search engine work?

Tags: android, seo, google-play

How do you improve the position of an app in Android Market search results? The apps don't seem to be sorted on downloads.

**Edit**: The scope of this question is limited to working with the Android Market search engine, of which there's little or no information. I changed the title to make it clearer.

Comment: If there's a better stack site to ask this, please let me know and I will gladly move the question there. Sorry in advance.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because the question is about SEO, not promotion (even if the answers so far are about promotion).

Comment: @EnderMB The Android Market app has a search engine. This question is about working with that particular search engine. Please don't change the subject of the question.

Comment: It is not SEO. It's the equivalent of improving your "stack overflow seo" by using its "search engine". A search function and a search engine are two entirely different things and your definition of search engines is both vastly incorrect and misleading to people who want to answer your question. The reason you're receiving only promotion related answers is because there is no such thing as SEO in relation to the Android market.

Comment: @EnderMB SEO is the process of improving ranking in search engine results. But even if we don't agree on the definition of SEO, changing the subject to "marketing" is broadening the scope of the question.

Comment: SEO is the process of optimising a web page for search engines. You are confusing it with SEM (Search Engine Marketing), hence the change to just marketing. Regardless, there is no application of SEO techniques to the Android marketplace unless you're looking to promote it through its own web page. I would suggest the changes I made in order to get relevant answers, otherwise I doubt other users will find the article in time to add their software/app marketing knowledge.

Comment: @EnderMB The "SEO" term is typically used in the context of web search engines, and I see your point. And I think a question about marketing techniques for Android apps is valid and interesting. It's just not the question I want to ask in this case. Do you think that the intent of the question is clearer with the new title?

Answer (score 12):

:-)

1. Make an app everyone wants, that gets high user ratings and lots of downloads
2. Update your app frequently, since it shows up at the top in the "Just in"-tab on every update
3. Use your Social Media Network (Create Facebook groups, start promoting smart on Twitter). Set up a user wiki where everyone can add content, discuss your app and get a real buzz around it.
4. Buy Google listings
5. Create a Blog discussing the app and its outstanding performance

EDIT: Almost forgot: Your app should be free, with a possibility to go pro (= paid).

Comment: All good general tips to get more downloads, but Android Market search results are not sorted by downloads.

Comment: Not only on downloads, no. It's a combination of (1) no of downloads, (2) user ratings and (3) no of user ratings. This is (to my knowledge) kept in the dark for us outside of the Open Handset Alliance. So the best we can do is use open sources to market our apps.

Comment: I would add that probably also the name of the app and the tags specified when publishing clearly influence the ranking.
Also it could be possible that the content of the description is taken into consideration...

Comment: I'd like to add a tip. Invest in some admob ads. It's the best thing you can do if you want downloads, beats making facebook groups and twitter campaigns. It also beats making adsense campaigns (even if these are targeted at android mobile devices). Also, when making the admob ads, don't choose one of the simple text ones. Uploaded your own banner and make it flashy.

Answer (score 3):

I would add to the answers:

- make your app in a way that can be extended with plugins by 3rd party coders, that means they create and submit their apps to the Market as extensions to your app, and that will raise the results

Comment: Thats a good one Pentium10. Something to take into account @hgpc.