# Android Market SEO - Getting to show up more often in the Android Market

Tags: android, seo

I just published my first application to the android marketplace.  However, when I search, I have to enter the exact name in order for it to come up.  Is there a way to enter app tags?

In the market app, my app doesn't even show any 'related' apps either.

How can I make my App more readily viewable?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417418/how-does-the-android-market-search-engine-work but I dont think it should be closed as off-topic as in the FAQ states "matters that are unique to the programming profession" are allowed and I think this question as well as the other fits that description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a tags section to your description is helpful and will get your app to show under more search phrases.  The catch is, there is more to Google's algorithm that generates hits for your app.  Here are some caveats that I've noticed after doing some simple research:

The title of the app gets a higher priority than the description.  So a tag in the description called "free wallpaper" isn't going to generate a higher return match than an app named "free wallpaper" unless other factors contribute and make it higher.

The number of app downloads generate a higher percentage.

I'm sure there are others but these were the main two contributors I could deduce from my research.

Comment: Thanks for all the Info, I'll edit the displayed text a little. :)

Answer (score 2):

I added a "TAGS:" section to the bottom of the description.  In it I just list single terms separated by commas.